# Fill a vector with weekdays only

Tags: r, date, vector

I know the start date `start` and the last date `maturity`. How can I fill in a vector with dates without taking weekends dates into account ? 
For instance, let's say :

```
> start = as.Date("2013-02-28");
> maturity = as.Date("2013-03-07");
```

I would like to get the following vector as a result :

```
results
[1] "2013-03-01" "2013-03-04" "2013-03-05" "2013-03-06" "2013-03-07"



> start = as.Date("2013-02-28");
> maturity = as.Date("2013-03-07");
> x <- seq(start,maturity,by = 1)
> x
[1] "2013-02-28" "2013-03-01" "2013-03-02" "2013-03-03" "2013-03-04" "2013-03-05"
[7] "2013-03-06" "2013-03-07"
> x <- x[!weekdays(x) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')]
> x
[1] "2013-02-28" "2013-03-01" "2013-03-02" "2013-03-03" "2013-03-04" "2013-03-05"
[7] "2013-03-06" "2013-03-07"
```

Same results... ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are probably a billion ways to do this with a variety of functions from multiple packages. But my first thought is to simply make a sequence and then remove the weekends:

```
x <- seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-12-31'),by = 1)
x <- x[!weekdays(x) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')]
```

This answer is valid only with an English based system. For instance, in a French version, 'Saturday' and 'Sunday' must be translated into 'samedi' and 'dimanche'

Answer (score 4):

This less human than @joran answer:) , but it is no local-time depending

```
dd <- seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-12-31'),by = 1)
dd[! (as.POSIXlt(dd)$wd %in% c(0,1))]
```

PS : another option , is to set locals before applying `weekdays`

```
tt <- Sys.getlocale('LC_TIME')
Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME','ENGLISH')
dd <- dd[!weekdays(x) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')]
Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME',tt)
```