# R how to sequence date for specific months

Tags: r, date

How can I sequence date from month October to next April for 60 years? I tried

```
seq(from=as.Date("1950-10-1"),to=as.Date("2011-12-31"),by="day")
```

but cannot figure out how to get ride of the months May to Sept. in between, any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I have a very strong desire to mark this as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15139768/324364). See `?months`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(date=seq(from=as.Date("1950-10-1"),to=as.Date("2011-12-31"),by="day"))
df <- within(df, { month  <-  as.numeric(format(date, "%m")) })
q <- with(df, df[month<5 | month>9,])
unique(q$month)
head(q$date)
```